# Regex to replace coderay code samples with ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, multiline

I'm writing a script to migrate some blog posts.

Each blog post may contain markdown-indented code samples. Some of which have a first line, starting with three colons and a language identifier.

```
    ::: ruby
    def test
      puts "meh"
    end
```

These are part of a larger text.

Now, for any given text I want to find these code blocks and replace them with this:

```
{% codeblock lang:ruby %}
def test
  puts "meh"
end
{% endcodeblock %}
```

In case there is no three colons or language identifier, I want to omit the `lang:<lang>` bit.

I'm currently stumped at how to write a regex to find these. All I can come up with is this draconian and not working beast:

```
/^\s{4}(:::(\w+))+\n(\s{4}.*)\n^\s{0}$/mi
```

See http://www.rubular.com/r/kycM8SDQLb for details.

What would be the proper way to update each post? I'm just working on the regexes, the ruby code won't be a problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

OK, it turned out that the newline problem came from my Opera browser.

When I check your original link in chrome, it seems that it is kind of working, but is matching too much.

So the only problem you have is to make your regex [ungreedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
^\s{4}(:::(\w+))+\n(\s{4}.*?)\n^$
```

See it [here on Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/yPZjQ3Y8K7)

**Original Answer:**

If I change your regex to

```
^\s{4}:::(\w+)\r\n( {4}.*?)^\r$
```

it will work, [see it on rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/066tPm46W7)

You seem to have (at least on Rubular) three problems in your regex:

1. A linebreak there is `\r\n`, so your `\n` alone does not match.
2. `$` does not really match a linebreak, it matches before a `\n`, so this will bite you if your linebreak is `\r\n`
3. {0} is useless, in fact rubular stops matching anything if I put it in somewhere.

And I changed the `.*` to the ungreedy version `.*?` otherwise it will match too much.

Comment: @halfelf, try [this link](http://www.rubular.com/r/2iUUWxlgIP), seems that the newline problem is not rubular specific, it is browser dependent. My original link is working in Opera.

Answer (score 0):

It is good that you are using the `m` option, but it does not make sense to use the `i` option as there is no alphabet in your regex. You may want to downcase or upcase etc. the language name after the match. Note that `\s` includes newline.

```
/^ {4}:::[ \t]*(\w+)[ \t]*\n((?: {4}[^\n]*\n)*)/m
```

Or if you might be using a non-linux, then

```
/^ {4}:::[ \t]*(\w+)[ \t]*#{$/}((?: {4}[^#{$/}]*#{$/})*)/m
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are parsing that code into text, try this:

```
str = %Q{:::ruby
def test
  puts "meh"
end}

str2 = %Q{def test
  puts "meh"
end}

str.gsub(/^\s*(:::\s(\w+))?((.|\s)+)/) do
  "{% codeblock#{" lang:#{$1}" if $1} %}#{$3}{% endcodeblock %}"
end
str2.gsub(/^\s*(:::\s(\w+))?((.|\s)+)/) do
  "{% codeblock#{" lang:#{$1}" if $1} %}#{$3}{% endcodeblock %}"
end
```

what can be adapted are the regex for the language name (maybe it won't catch c++) and blank characters at the beginning/end, other than that, this does the trick, i think